# Error configuring Google services: Error Domain=com.google.greenhouse Code=-106 Missing expected subspecs

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I am integrating [Google cloud messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).

I install google cloud messaging by cocoapods.

```
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
```

My GoogleService-Info.plist:-

[image]

I am getting error while running the workspace:-

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error configuring Google
>   services: Error Domain=com.google.greenhouse Code=-106 "Missing
>   expected subspecs." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing expected
>   subspecs.

Am I missing any another dependant cocoapod or project settings?

Comment: Any reason why you're not trying to use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) instead? :)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you use `GGLContext` class to setup google services. And in `GoogleServices-Info.plist` there are presents enabled services which you are not included libraries for. I my case there were `IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED = YES` and `IS_ADS_ENABLED = YES`.

```
NSError* configureError;                                                     
[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];            
if (configureError) {                                                        
    RLog(@"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);          
    return;                                                                  
}                                                                            

_gcmSenderID = [[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configuration] gcmSenderID];
```

I also faced with that issue then I downloaded `GoogleServices-Info.plist` from **Firebase Console**. To solve the issue I removed `GGLContext` class and hardcoded `_gcmSenderID` by the value obtained from `GCM_SENDER_ID` key in origin file.

```
_gcmSenderID = @"778899223344";
```

But you can just disable these services by setting to `NO` in `GoogleServices-Info.plist` file